# Laravel Symoblic link not working on shared hosting

Tags: laravel, shared-hosting

I modified the using filesystem configuration as

```
'local' => [
'driver' => 'local',
'root' => public_path('images'),
'throw' => false,
],
```

So on local system, I'm storing the all the files in public directory

```
localhost:8000/public/images
```

by using file upload

```
$this->logo->storeAs('brand', 'abc.jpg');
```

I can directly access images using

```
url('images')
```

but when i upload my project to live, images are not displaying. I tried and executed the following route, but fail to load images on live server

```
Route::get('/link', function () {
    $target = public_path();
    $link = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/new';
    if (symlink($target, $link))
        die("SUCCESS");
    else
        die("ERROR");
});
```

Comment: I think that you could use a folder instead of symlink (public/images)

Comment: @Med.ZAIRI When i tried to use folder, It's not linking.

Comment: Sample error: https://www.reawda.com/error.png

Comment: Solution found. add to index.php file:  $app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__;
});